# How can I use xlsxwriter to create one textbox on a worksheet with multiple formats?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using xlswriter to create a textbox in a Excel worksheet as follows:

```
import xlsxwriter

text = 'this is line 1 \nthis is line 2 \nthis is line 3'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('c:/tmp/test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Information')
options = {
            'width':200,
            'height':200,
            'font': {
                      'bold': True,
                      'size': 12
                    }
}
worksheet.insert_textbox(1, 1,text,options)
workbook.close()
```

the result is:

[image]

What I want is to format lines 1, 2 and 3 differently.
I can do it manually on Excel, by selecting the text and changing the font to look as follows:

[image]

How can I do this in Python?
I can achieve this if I write to a cell but how can I do multiple formats in a textbox?

Comment: That isn't currently possible with xlsxwriter and unlikely to be added in the future.

Comment: You can do this with Xlwings (if you can run Excel locally)

Comment: Xlwings looks like a good solution, specially with its Google Sheets support.   Thanks